# Getting info from json column in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have json column where i save my orders data in it, code below is sample of that data:

```
[{"id":27,"name":"new product","price":7246,"quantity":"1","attributes":[],"conditions":[]}]
```

with code above if i have such loop in my edit page i'm able to get orders info:

```
@foreach($order->product_data as $data)
{{ $data['quantity'] }}
@endforeach
```

until here everything is good, but the problem when comes that my order has attributes `"attributes":[],` then i get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

and my data in json column is like:

```
"[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":\"1\",\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Red\",\"price\":\"5000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"22\\\"\",\"price\":\"900000.00\"}}],\"conditions\":[]}]"
```

as you see this order has 2 attributes. (can be more or less).

## additional

this is how i get those data in order model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'product_data' => 'array',
  ];
```

**any idea why i get that error and how i can get my attributes data no matter if my order has attribute or not?**

## UPDATE

if i open edit page of order without attribute and `dd` the result will be like:

```
array:6 [▼
  "id" => 27
  "name" => "new product"
  "price" => 7246
  "quantity" => "1"
  "attributes" => []
  "conditions" => []
]
```

if load the same on order with attributes get the error above.

Comment: could you please show us what you have done with attributes??

Comment: what do you mean? what you need to see? so i can get it for you

Comment: the reason you are having error `"attributes":[]`, what have you done with this, show the code which gives this error

Comment: @Sohel0415 i did nothing not even single word! base on my loop (i share in question) directly it gives this error.

Comment: How do you access `attributes[]` in your view?

Comment: @linktoahref i don't! that's the issue still i didn't solve.

Comment: @mafortis Could you update `dd` of order with attributes

Comment: that's the result on order with attributes `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` no dd will return

Comment: @mafortis  try like this hope it will help foreach($order->product_data as $data)  if(!$data->attributes->isEmpty())  foreach($data->attribute as $d)      {{$data}} endforeach else
{{ $data['quantity'] }}  endif
endforeach

Comment: it seems that  your `$order->product_data` do not have value for some reason, trace for further details and to stop that particular error, you can add `if ` condition before `foreach`

Comment: @bipin still have same error.

Comment: @JigarShah i say if what before foreach?

Comment: `if($order->product_data)` to check whether it contains data before looping through it. You can check for `is_array` as well.

Comment: Could you comment out the `foreach` loop and dump the order having attributes`dd($order)`

Comment: @linktoahref here you go https://ibb.co/ibLOGH

Comment: @JigarShah it returns that it is not array! `@if(!is_array($order->product_data))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only allow to print data if exists and having the format we are expecting ,please add necessary conditions to your code like below which may prevent from getting the errors

Assuming the array you have in post is data you need to print.

```
@if($order->product_data) // check product_data value or not , also add key exists if needed
    @if(is_array($order->product_data)) // check for product_data is array or not
        @foreach($order->product_data as $data)
            {{ $data['quantity'] // if array }}
            {{ $data->quantity // if object }}
            @if($data->attributes) 
                @foreach($data->attributes as $attribute) // loop through attributes                    
                    {{ $attribute->nameOfTheProperty // if object }}
                @endforeach        
            @endif            
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
```

But better to handle the data in controller if possible

**update**:

you need to convert your data into array, as your attribute property will be blank array if not having value otherwise it will be stdObject.

so your code should be : (`$order->product_data` should be an array if not then convert it to an array)

```
@if($order->product_data) 
    @if(is_array($order->product_data))  // assuming array
        @foreach($order->product_data as $data)
            {{ $data['quantity'] // if array }}            
            @if(count($data['attributes']) > 0) // **checked for blank array**
                @foreach($data->attributes as $attribute) // loop through attributes                    
                    {{ $attribute['attr']['label'] }}
                    {{ $attribute['attr']['price'] }}
                @endforeach        
            @endif            
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: this will take care of error but still i don't know how to get attributes?

Comment: second issue: on order `without attribute` is return quantity, but on order `with attribute` it returns nothing.

Comment: updated my code to get `attributes`. you need to add those specific conditions before accessing `attributes`

Comment: returns nothing. :\

Comment: I have just explained you how it can be handled, pasting this code will not work directly. You need to adjust conditions based on datatype of input and your requirement

Comment: please take a look at this https://ibb.co/idsbmH . i cannot get results better than this! when i go to order `with` attributes it gives me foreach error.

Comment: check the update portion, you have different datatype for `attributes` property so it not working, please convert it array to have same format with and without value of `attributes`.

Comment: it will show quantity on order `without` attribute and nothing on order `with` attribute`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164528/discussion-between-jigar-shah-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

Tried with your sample data, and that executed without any error.

```
$json = "[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":\"1\",\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Red\",\"price\":\"5000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"22\\\"\",\"price\":\"900000.00\"}}],\"conditions\":[]}]";

$jsonAsArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($jsonAsArray as $data) {
    echo $data['quantity'] . "\n";

    if (! empty($data['attributes']) ) {
        if (is_array($data['attributes'])) {
            foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute) {
                echo $attribute['attr']['label'] . ' ' . $attribute['attr']['price'] . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1

Red 5000.00

22" 900000.00
```

In your case, the `product_data` is not cast as an array.
You could try Defining An [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your Order model, and remove the cast property of `product_data`

```
public function getProductDataAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, TRUE);
}
```

Or Manually decode the json in your loop

```
@foreach (json_decode($order->product_data, TRUE) as $data)
    {{ $data['quantity'] }}

    @if (! empty($data['attributes']))

        @foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute)

            {{ $attribute['attr']['label'] }} {{ $attribute['attr']['price'] }}

        @endforeach

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: ok, i added `public function getProductDataAttribute($value)` to my model now what should i do?

Comment: Try accessing the order's `$order->product_data` using the original `foreach` loop that you've used in your question

Comment: i have this now `@foreach($order->product_data as $data)  @foreach($data['attributes'] as $attribute)  {{ $attribute->price }} @endforeach @endforeach ` no error but nothing prints also.

Comment: What's the error? The JSON is cast into array, and you are accessing it as objects `{{ $attribute->price }}` should be `{{ $attribute['attr']['price'] }}`

Comment: no error. nothing will print! wait i share some screenshots.

Comment: bro the thing is because i use `casts` i do not need `json_decode` + there is strange issue you can find it here https://ibb.co/idsbmH

Comment: Could you do `dd($order->product_data)` for order with attributes (Outside of foreach loop) and check if the result is cast into an array?

Comment: rsult is `null`

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did mine (category is a json column in the DB):

```
    <div class="category">
     <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach ( json_decode( $code->category ) as $category)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">{{$category}}</span>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
 </div>
```

You just have to json_decode your json column to get an array and iterate over it. that's it, cheers.